# Generic Method with Generic foreach

Tags: c#, generics, abstraction, c#-8.0

I have 2 Methods that are almost the same but have little differences and I want to make 1 Generic Method to do it all.

Method 1

```cs
public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data)
{
    List<DataGraficoNgxChart> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart> { };
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion))
        {
            var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion);
            Series serie = new Series { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha };
            sub.Series.Add(serie);
        }
        else
        {
            DataGraficoNgxChart evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart
            {
                Name = item.Clasificacion,
                Series = new List<Series> { new Series { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha } }
            };
            series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
        }
    }
    return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
}
```

Method 2

```cs
public List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<Rentabilidad> data)
{
    List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> { };
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Fecha))
        {
            var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Fecha);
            SeriesInvertidaserie = new SeriesInvertida{ Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Clasificacion};
            sub.Series.Add(serie);
        }
        else
        {
            DataGraficoNgxChartInvertidaevolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida
            {
                Name = item.Fecha,
                SeriesInvertida= new List<SeriesInvertida> { new Series { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Clasificacion } }
            };
            series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
        }
    }
    return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
}
```

And my classes are:

```cs
    private class DataGraficoNgxChart
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Series> Series { get; set; }
    }
    private class DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida
    {
        public DateTime Name { get; set; }
        public List<SeriesInvertida> Series { get; set; }
    }
    private class Series
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Name { get; set; }
    }
    private class SeriesInvertida
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

So far, I managed to make the clases Generic:

```cs
    public class DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>
    {
        public N Name { get; set; }
        public List<Series<T>> Series { get; set; }
    }
    public class Series<T>
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public T Name { get; set; }
    }
```

But I struggle doing the Generic Method:

```cs
    public List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<X, N, T>(List<X> data, Predicate<X> ejexName, b ejey ) // Trying to pass the parameters, but might be wrong
    {
        List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> { };
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion)) // item properties gives me error (obviously, it doesn't have a way to know them)
            {
                var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion); // Other error here
                Series<T> serie = new Series<T> { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha }; // And here
                sub.Series.Add(serie);
            }
            else
            {
                DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T> evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>
                {
                    Name = item.Clasificacion, // And here again
                    Series = new List<Series<T>> { new Series<T> { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha } } // And and again...
                };
                series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
            }
        }
        return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
    }
```

The code is wrong (its a WIP) but I don't know how to call the generic objects properties inside the for each.

This is my **complete** class so far with the old methods and the generic one.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace GpiWebApp.Services
{
    public interface INgxChartSpecification
    {
        List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<X, N, T>(List<X> data, Predicate<X> ejexName, b ejey);
        List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<RentabilidadClasificacion> data);
        List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data);
        List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> GenerarDataGraficoInvertidoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data);
    }

    public sealed class NgxChartSpecification : INgxChartSpecification
    {
        public NgxChartSpecification()
        {
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<X, N, T>(List<X> data, Predicate<X> ejexName, b ejey) // Trying to pass the parameters, but might be wrong
        {
            List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>> { };
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion)) // item properties gives me error (obviously, it doesn't have a way to know them)
                {
                    var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion); // Other error here
                    Series<T> serie = new Series<T> { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha }; // And here
                    sub.Series.Add(serie);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T> evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>
                    {
                        Name = item.Clasificacion, // And here again
                        Series = new List<Series<T>> { new Series<T> { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha } } // And and again...
                    };
                    series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
                }
            }
            return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<RentabilidadClasificacion> data)
        {
            List<DataGraficoNgxChart> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart> { };
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.dscArbol))
                {
                    var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.dscArbol);
                    Series serie = new Series { Value = item.ValorCuota, Name = item.FechaCierre };
                    sub.Series.Add(serie);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGraficoNgxChart evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart
                    {
                        Name = item.dscArbol,
                        Series = new List<Series> { new Series { Value = item.ValorCuota, Name = item.FechaCierre } }
                    };
                    series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
                }
            }
            return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data)
        {
            List<DataGraficoNgxChart> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart> { };
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion))
                {
                    var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Clasificacion);
                    Series serie = new Series { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha };
                    sub.Series.Add(serie);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGraficoNgxChart evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart
                    {
                        Name = item.Clasificacion,
                        Series = new List<Series> { new Series { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Fecha } }
                    };
                    series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
                }
            }
            return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> GenerarDataGraficoInvertidoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data)
        {
            List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> { };
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Fecha))
                {
                    var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Fecha);
                    SeriesInvertida serie = new SeriesInvertida { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Clasificacion };
                    sub.Series.Add(serie);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida
                    {
                        Name = item.Fecha,
                        Series = new List<SeriesInvertida> { new SeriesInvertida { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Clasificacion } }
                    };
                    series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
                }
            }
            return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }

    }

    public class DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>
    {
        public N Name { get; set; }
        public List<Series<T>> Series { get; set; }
    }

    public class Series<T>
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public T Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGraficoNgxChart
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Series> Series { get; set; }
    }
    public class Series
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida
    {
        public DateTime Name { get; set; }
        public List<SeriesInvertida> Series { get; set; }
    }
    public class SeriesInvertida
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RentabilidadClasificacion
    {
        public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }
        public decimal IdArbol { get; set; }
        public string dscArbol { get; set; }
        public decimal Patrimonio { get; set; }
        public decimal Aporet { get; set; }
        public decimal Utilidad { get; set; }
        public decimal Rentabilidad { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorCuota { get; set; }
        public decimal Distribucion { get; set; }
        public decimal Nivel { get; set; }
    }

    public class EvolucionCartera
    {
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Clasificacion { get; set; }
        public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
        public decimal NivelArbol { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Any help-ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) may help.

Comment: You need an common interface or base class, and maybe pass lamba or something like that. I checked you code, but I won't compile as some things are missing. Please check that you are making a minimal example in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With you updated code example, you could do this.

Create a common interface:

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Lookupname { get; }
    DateTime Name { get; }
    decimal? Value { get; }
}
```

Create a new method GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart with a `where` constraint and let it use `IItem` properties instead of `RentabilidadClasificacion`/`EvolucionCartera`:

```
public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<T>(List<T> data)
where T : IItem // added 
{
    List<DataGraficoNgxChart> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart> { };
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Lookupname)) // changed
        {
            var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Lookupname);  // changed
            Series serie = new Series { Value = item.Value, Name = item.Name };  // changed
            sub.Series.Add(serie);
        }
        else
        {
            DataGraficoNgxChart evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart
            {
                Name = item.Lookupname,  // changed
                Series = new List<Series> { new Series { Value = item.Value, Name = item.Name } }  // changed
            };
            series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
        }
    }
    return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
}
```

and of course, let `RentabilidadClasificacion` and `EvolucionCartera` implement the interface. I choose here for [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```
public class RentabilidadClasificacion : NgxChartSpecification.IItem
{
    public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }
    public decimal IdArbol { get; set; }
    public string dscArbol { get; set; }
    public decimal Patrimonio { get; set; }
    public decimal Aporet { get; set; }
    public decimal Utilidad { get; set; }
    public decimal Rentabilidad { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorCuota { get; set; }
    public decimal Distribucion { get; set; }
    public decimal Nivel { get; set; }

    #region Implementation of IItem
    string NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Lookupname => dscArbol;
    DateTime NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Name => FechaCierre;
    decimal? NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Value => ValorCuota;

    #endregion
}

public class EvolucionCartera : NgxChartSpecification.IItem
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Clasificacion { get; set; }
    public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
    public decimal NivelArbol { get; set; }

    #region Implementation of IItem
    DateTime NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Name => Fecha;
    decimal? NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Value => Monto;
    string NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Lookupname => Clasificacion;

    #endregion
}
```

Now you could create:

```
public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data)
{
    return GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<EvolucionCartera>(data);
} 
public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<RentabilidadClasificacion> data)
{
    return GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<RentabilidadClasificacion>(data);
}
```

All classes, this compiles!

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace GpiWebApp.Services
{
    public interface INgxChartSpecification
    {
        List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<RentabilidadClasificacion> data);
        List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data);
        List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> GenerarDataGraficoInvertidoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data);
    }

    public sealed class NgxChartSpecification : INgxChartSpecification
    {
        public NgxChartSpecification()
        {
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data)
        {
            return GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<EvolucionCartera>(data);
        }
        public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart(List<RentabilidadClasificacion> data)
        {
            return GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<RentabilidadClasificacion>(data);
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChart> GenerarDataGraficoNgxChart<T>(List<T> data)
        where T : IItem // added 
        {
            List<DataGraficoNgxChart> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChart> { };
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Lookupname)) // changed
                {
                    var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Lookupname);  // changed
                    Series serie = new Series { Value = item.Value, Name = item.Name };  // changed
                    sub.Series.Add(serie);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGraficoNgxChart evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChart
                    {
                        Name = item.Lookupname,  // changed
                        Series = new List<Series> { new Series { Value = item.Value, Name = item.Name } }  // changed
                    };
                    series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
                }
            }
            return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }

        public interface IItem
        {
            string Lookupname { get; }
            DateTime Name { get; }
            decimal? Value { get; }
        }

        public List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> GenerarDataGraficoInvertidoNgxChart(List<EvolucionCartera> data)
        {
            List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> series = new List<DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida> { };
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                if (series.Exists(s => s.Name == item.Fecha))
                {
                    var sub = series.Find(s => s.Name == item.Fecha);
                    SeriesInvertida serie = new SeriesInvertida { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Clasificacion };
                    sub.Series.Add(serie);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida evolucionPatrimonio = new DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida
                    {
                        Name = item.Fecha,
                        Series = new List<SeriesInvertida> { new SeriesInvertida { Value = item.Monto, Name = item.Clasificacion } }
                    };
                    series.Add(evolucionPatrimonio);
                }
            }
            return series.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }

    }

    public class DataGraficoNgxChart<N, T>
    {
        public N Name { get; set; }
        public List<Series<T>> Series { get; set; }
    }

    public class Series<T>
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public T Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGraficoNgxChart
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Series> Series { get; set; }
    }
    public class Series
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGraficoNgxChartInvertida
    {
        public DateTime Name { get; set; }
        public List<SeriesInvertida> Series { get; set; }
    }
    public class SeriesInvertida
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RentabilidadClasificacion : NgxChartSpecification.IItem
    {
        public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }
        public decimal IdArbol { get; set; }
        public string dscArbol { get; set; }
        public decimal Patrimonio { get; set; }
        public decimal Aporet { get; set; }
        public decimal Utilidad { get; set; }
        public decimal Rentabilidad { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorCuota { get; set; }
        public decimal Distribucion { get; set; }
        public decimal Nivel { get; set; }

        #region Implementation of IItem
        string NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Lookupname => dscArbol;
        DateTime NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Name => FechaCierre;
        decimal? NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Value => ValorCuota;

        #endregion
    }

    public class EvolucionCartera : NgxChartSpecification.IItem
    {
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Clasificacion { get; set; }
        public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
        public decimal NivelArbol { get; set; }

        #region Implementation of IItem
        DateTime NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Name => Fecha;
        decimal? NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Value => Monto;
        string NgxChartSpecification.IItem.Lookupname => Clasificacion;

        #endregion
    }

}
```